# I can't get the value retrieved using MGTwitterEngine(iPhone) for Twitter API 1.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, mgtwitterengine, yajl

I use MGTwitterEngine(iPhone).
But I can't get the value retrieved using MGTwitterYAJLParser…
Following is described 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets.

here is my code….
MGTwitterSearchYAJLParser.m

```
    - (void)addValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    //if for some reason there are no dictionaries, exit here
    if (!_dictionaries || [_dictionaries count] == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *lastDictionary = [_dictionaries lastObject];
    if([[lastDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        NSMutableArray *array = [lastDictionary objectForKey:key];
        [array addObject:value];
    }else{
        [lastDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
    }

#if DEBUG_PARSING
    NSLog(@"parsed item: %@ = %@ (%@)", key, value, NSStringFromClass([value class]));
#endif
}

- (void)startDictionaryWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
#if DEBUG_PARSING
    NSLog(@"status: dictionary start = %@", key);
#endif

    if (!_dictionaries)
    {
        _dictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if (!_dictionaryKeys)
    {
        _dictionaryKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    //add a new dictionary to the array
    NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [_dictionaries addObject:newDictionary];
    [newDictionary release];

    //add a key for the above dictionary to the array
    [_dictionaryKeys addObject:(key) ? key : @""];
}

- (void)endDictionary
{
    if (_dictionaries && _dictionaryKeys && [_dictionaries count] > 0 && [_dictionaryKeys count] > 0)
    {
        //is this the root dictionary?
        if ([_dictionaries count] == 1)
        {
            //one dictionary left, so it must be the root
            NSMutableDictionary *rootDictionary = [_dictionaries lastObject];

            //set the request type in the root dictionary
            [rootDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:requestType] forKey:TWITTER_SOURCE_REQUEST_TYPE];

            //send the root dictionary to the super class
            [self _parsedObject:rootDictionary];
            [parsedObjects addObject:rootDictionary];
        }
        else
        {
            //child dictionary found
            //add the child dictionary to its parent dictionary
            NSMutableDictionary *parentDictionary = [_dictionaries objectAtIndex:[_dictionaries count] - 2];
            [parentDictionary setObject:[_dictionaries lastObject] forKey:[_dictionaryKeys lastObject]];
        }

        //remove the last dictionary since it has been joined with its parent (or was the root dictionary)
        //also remove the corresponding key
        [_dictionaries removeLastObject];
        [_dictionaryKeys removeLastObject];
    }
#if DEBUG_PARSING
    NSLog(@"status: dictionary end");
#endif
}

- (void)startArrayWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    arrayDepth++;

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self addValue:newArray forKey:key];

#if DEBUG_PARSING
    NSLog(@"status: array start = %@", key);
#endif
}

- (void)endArray
{
#if DEBUG_PARSING
    NSLog(@"status: array end");
#endif

    arrayDepth--;
    [self clearCurrentKey];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_dictionaries release];
    [_dictionaryKeys release];
    [_status release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```